# Netbeans errors on files that compile

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, mysql-connector

I am new to qt, qmake, etc.

I've created a .pri file that includes:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$QXMPP_INCLUDE_DIR \
               /path/to/mysql-connector-c++-1.0.5/

LIBS += $$QXMPP_LIBS \
        -lmysqlcppconn
```

When I

qmake -o Makefile
make
./myProject

or simply hit run in the Netbeans IDE my project compiles and runs successfully.

However, my Netbeans IDE does not realize I have included the mysqlcppconn library I think because I have errors in my code as shown in the pictures below.  How can I get rid of these errors?  My suspicion is that I should I tell Netbeans that I've included the mysqlcppconn library.  If that is correct how can I do that?  Or is there something else I should do?

Thanks!

[image: error]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define include directory in netbeans project properties. 
right click on project and go to properties there define include directory in c++ option.

Answer (score 1):

While i must admit I have no direct answer to your problem, I do have a number of surgestions:

1. The project file is supposed to be named .pro (though I guess that was just a typo in the post)
2. While there should be no problem in using Netbeans I will provide you with the personal recommendation of using Qt Creator as your IDE. In my own opinion it is a great IDE, and it is designed with Qt in mind.
3. For SQL i would recommend you take a look at [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsqldatabase.html)

Comment: The first answer worked and was what I was looking for.  I didn't know about QSqlDatabase.  I'll look into it and probably use it over mysqlconnector because it looks like it is better documented.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I meant a pri, not pro, file.  I believe qmake treats a pri file the same way it treats a pro file.  You can include pri files using include(mypri.pri) in pro files.  This can allow you to organize your make strategy of the project.